# Java programming with Weka - special steps to increase Java heap?

Tags: java, weka

I've got a Java program in Netbeans running on Windows 7. Windows and Java are both 64-bit. My computer has 16GB of RAM, mostly free.

When I run the program I hit a step wherein I'm building an algorithm and I get

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Everytime, **regardless of the `-Xmx` and `-Xms` settings** and also **regardless of the size** of the input data set.

Now, I know that if I were using the Weka program, rather than programming with the Weka library, that `-Xmx` would not work for some reason and you have to instead edit the `.ini`. Is there some comparable special step needed to increase the heap when using the library for Java programming?

The full error is:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   at weka.filters.supervised.attribute.NominalToBinary.convertInstanceNominal(NominalToBinary.java:619)
>   at weka.filters.supervised.attribute.NominalToBinary.convertInstance(NominalToBinary.java:460)
>   at weka.filters.supervised.attribute.NominalToBinary.input(NominalToBinary.java:225)
>   at weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(Filter.java:692)
>   at weka.classifiers.trees.lmt.LMTNode.tryLogistic(LMTNode.java:515)
>   at weka.classifiers.trees.lmt.LMTNode.buildClassifier(LMTNode.java:183)
>   at weka.classifiers.trees.LMT.buildClassifier(LMT.java:277)
>   at RRO.chooseAlgorithm.chooseAlgorithm(chooseAlgorithm.java:86)
>   at RRO.SilverBullet.main(SilverBullet.java:36)
> C:\Users\jmiller\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
> ```
>
> Java returned: 1
>       BUILD FAILED (total time: 23 seconds)

Comment: No special steps. Have you observed the heap (with `jvisualvm` for example) to see what's happening?

Comment: @Kayaman I don't really know how to do that, but I will research it. Thanks for the update/suggestion in the comment. I am on it.

Comment: Is it possible that Weka still uses the .ini file, even when used as a library? Everything I found on this subject referred to that file.

Comment: @Laf Not really, unless the libary is being used in a weird way. If it's used like any other Java lib, it won't have anything to say about memory settings since it will have to use the ones provided by the parent JVM. The reason you can only find things about the `.ini` file is because Weka is a Java program, so it's really hard to differentiate in Google that you're talking about a *library*, not the standalone program.

Comment: Are there any troubleshooting steps I can try? I've written Java Weka programs before on a server without any problems, but several things were different including OS, size of resources, etc. While high memory usage is possible, it seems weird to me that I can't train an algorithm at all on a small test data set (like the Iris data) with a few GB's of RAM available via -Xmx. I've downloaded and am learning `jvisualvm` right now. **Update** Actually https://visualvm.github.io/idesupport.html tells me just to use Netbeans Profiler instead of jvisualvm. I'm on it.

Comment: OK so based on the profiler it seems that the amount of memory used is scaling exponentially with data size. At 100 rows 250MB were used, then at 1,000 rows it went up to 6GB and threw the heap size error.